# why does my air conditioner run when at set point

Tags: thermostat

my 10 year old a/c now starts even though house is at set point. if  I  raise set point it will shut down. all day long with set point at 79 it will start,  run and shut down again with ambient temp always at  the same reading. I have changed out three different thermostats with no change.

Comment: Is there a second thermostat? What are your settings inside the thermostat do you realize that they do not turn on and shut off at the set point? Some will not turn on until 2 degrees over the set point and not turn off until 1-2 under the set point to reduce cycling. These settings are usually programmable and if changing thermostats without changing the programming they may all run the same (common issue). How cold is the thermostat saying it is getting to?

Comment: Brand/model of the AC and the thermostat would be most helpful. Were all 3 thermostats the same brand/model or were they different?

Comment: How can you tell whether the temperature is 79.2 or 79.8?

Comment: Does the A/C run normally other than that? It sounds like you might have a different problem altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Because the tstat thinks its smart. between adaptive intelligent recovery and monotoring your system, it anticipates when it needs to run and it also lies about whether they system is really at set point or not.   I have a honeywell 7600 (I think) that does stuff like this. tstat says it's at set point, but it keep running.  In heat mode, if it indicates set point but keeps running I raise set point a few degrees and suddenly (in a few minutes)  it indicates temp is below previous set point, even though the system was running continuously!    I guess it can only lie for so long, because it has a conscience!.

Comment: Seems like every time they add the word smart to something, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation.

Except in my case it is the Fan only that runs not the Compressor.

My understanding is, it does that on purpose.

It shuts down the compressor at set point, but uses the fan to recycle the conditioned air for distribution.

Comment: I think the question is about frequent cycling. Not about running all the time. Fan running all the time (i.e., whether compressor is on or off) is usually a feature of the thermostat - some love it, some hate it, so it is normally configurable typically by setting Fan = On vs. Auto.